# How to print values according to same lines from two different text files

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted the user to input a particular product name (which is saved in a file) and accordingly I wanted to print out price of the product (saved in a different file), but not able to do so.

I have just started out programming, so it's new to me.

```
def find_in_file(f) :
    myfile = open("file1.txt")
    products =  myfile.read()
    products = products.splitlines()
    if f in products:
        return "Product is in list"
    else:
        return "Product is not in list"

def printing_in_file(p) : 
    myprice = open("file2.txt")
    price =  myprice.read()
    price = price.splitlines()
        return price

if code in sec_code.values():
    product = input("Enter product name:   ")
    print(printing_in_file(p))
```

I expected the price to be the output, but I am getting **name 'p' is not defined**.

Comment: Do you notice that your two functions have same name?

Comment: What is sec_code?

Comment: sec_code is security code. That part is working fine.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `printing_in_file(product)`? But `p` isn't used at all in your functions...

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess that the current code shown will raise a SyntaxError/IndentationError before it raises a NameError. Please post a [mcve] that reproduces your problem. This is generally more favourable and will assist debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer below works, but it is not complete, because you did not provide samples of your input files.**

The code that you provided does not have a 'p' variable, so I replace it with the variable *product*. I created *bool* values for the returns in the function *find_product* (which was named *find_in_file*).  If the inputted product name is an exact match (this will create problems) then a bool value of True is return. Next the code will call the function *find_product_price* (which was named *printing_in_file*) for the product name. I had to create files containing product names and prices, because you did not provide sample files as part of your question.

This code works, but it has limitation, because I do not know the exact format of your inputs files or sec_code values. With additional information this code can be improved or something new might replace some of it with something better.

Good luck with this coding problem.

```
def find_product(product_name) :
  inventory_file = open('tmpFile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
  products =  inventory_file.read()
  products = products.splitlines()
  if product_name in products:
     return True
  else:
     return False

def find_product_price(product_name) :
  product_prices =  open('tmpFile01.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
  prices =  product_prices.read()
  price = prices.splitlines()
  if product_name in price:
     return price

product = input("Enter product name: ")
product_search = find_product(product)
if product_search == True:
  print ('The product is available.')
  print(find_product_price(product))
  # outputs 
  ['cisco router $350']

elif product_search == False:
  print (f'{product} are not available for purchase.')
```